Do all TCP packets from same http request take same route? If not, how can I better understand where each went?
I understand TCP has a max size for each packet. This limit is probably easily reached with data-heavy responses.
Therefore do all these packets follow the same route (image of a train) or are they routed independently ?
Regardless of the answer, how can I figure out the routes taken by these packets? tcptraceroute is not bad but as I understand there is not guarantee my following legitimate http request will take the same route, even assuming it hits the website at the same hosting location.

Isn't the whole point of the Interweb that it will always seek the most efficient route available, whether or not that route was equally efficient S seconds ago, or might be as useful S seconds from now?

The path of a packet through the network is usually decided at layer 3 (IP) per packet by each router involved, i.e. independent from being part of the same "connection" (which is a layer 4 concept, i.e TCP, UDP) or "request" (which is a layer 7 concept, i.e. HTTP).
This does not mean though that packets within a connection/request will actually take different path. Usually they will take the same path (since it is the optimal one) but there is no guarantee for this. Since it is unlikely that the optimal path changes routers might also optimize for this case by caching previous decisions.
There are concepts like source routing where the sender might decide parts of the route the packet should take, but this is usually not used and many routers would ignore such IP extensions or discard the packets.
There is no way to detect which path an individual packet arriving at the destination actually took.

Many routers have a concept of "flows", but yes, on an internet router scale, they don't bother - they'd have millions of flows to track. MPLS helps this a little by leaving the path selection up to the ingress router, but intervening routers can handle that labeled path via multiple physical paths.

@Ricky: Sure, small SoHo "router" have a concept of states - but for NAT and not for routing. And these don't do much of a routing "decision" anyway, since they got a default route from the ISP.

Cisco IOS (etc.) ip route-cache flow NEXT. (available even on very big iron.) Even route-cache cef will pin the adjacency by default. (Linux stupidly removed the software route-cache many years ago.)

@Ricky: thanks for the input. I've reworded the answer to address your input.

Although I've never worked with "big" routers myself, I remember some Juniper documentation (e.g. its OSPF configuration) instructing the user to switch the router to "per-packet mode" for OSPF to work, which implies that by default it uses some kind of flow-based routing, probably similar to what Ricky mentioned.

@Ricky Speaking of which, I believe Linux now has something similar using nftables flow tables: https://firewalld.org/2023/05/nftables-flowtable

@Ricky many routers hash a few fields from the packet header to choose from one of several equivalent paths, without storing any state per flow

There are quite a few situations where traffic may be sent via different links (for load-balancing or other reasons), and depending on where those links go the full route may be very much the same (different links but same routers) or completely different (though that is unusual). This can frequently be seen in traceroute output where multiple IPs will be returned for the same hop. In some cases you can get pretty hard to read output...

IP packets, even those that contain TCP segments, are routed independently, regardless of what packets came before. It is possible that the IP packets containing a single TCP stream may take different routes.
That is the point of IP. IP was created to automatically route around damage (think nuclear war where a network routing node is destroyed, which was a driving force for the government funding to develop IP). To that end, IP was designed so that each packet is routed independently. In all probability, the IP packets containing a single stream will follow the same path, but there are reasons that may not be true, including changes in the the path or multipath routing.
Traceroute is a tool that is useful in your own network where you know how packets should go, but it is not useful on networks you do not know, including the public Internet. Some Internet carriers look for and reroute traceroute packets to prevent people from casually discovering their network topology. You really have no way to know how packets are routed once they leave your network.

"think nuclear war where a network routing node is destroyed" or, maybe, just someone unplugging a network cable...

@TripeHound, the threat of nuclear war was a driving force behind the government funding that was used to create IP.


I understand TCP has a max size for each packet.

That is the maximum segment size MSS.

This limit is probably easily reached with data-heavy responses.

Any non-trivial responses and even requests may exceed MSS. With the commonly used PPPoE, the IP MTU is 1492 bytes and the MSS over IPv4 is 1452 bytets (1492 - 20 bytes IPv4 - 20 bytes TCP overhead).

Therefore do all these packets follow the same route (image of a train) or are they routed independently ?

TCP is transported by IP packets and those are generally routed independently. However, usually the route doesn't change and the IP packets/TCP segments in a flow take the same path.

how can I figure out the routes taken by these packets? tcptraceroute is not bad but as I understand there is not guarantee my following legitimate http request will take the same route, even assuming it hits the website at the same hosting location.

Usually, traceroute (using UDP datagrams or ICMP packets) displays the same path that TCP segments take but as you stated, there's no guarantee. However, you can instruct Linux traceroute to send TCP port 80/443 SYNs, ie. fake HTTP/S probes, so the path should match the real one: traceroute -T -p 80 (or -p 443). (man traceroute)

As others have said, routing is normally handled in the IP layer. There may be caching that tries to use a consistent path for all segments in a TCP connection, but that's available or not at each step in the path.
This is one of the reasons that tools like traceroute send multiple probes for each hop. If there's load balancing over multiple paths, you'll see each of them in the output.
These are all just potential paths. There's no practical way to tell what path an actual connection is using. IP has the "record route" option, but this is not very useful. It's often disabled on routers for security reasons; the size of the field only allows for about 9 hops to be recorded, which is not usually enough on the modern Internet; and the recorded route can only be accessed on the destination system (it could also enable the option when replying, but routing on the Internet is not symmetric).

TCP (and comparable protocols including UDP and ICMP) is built on top of IP. A TCP message is broken into a sequence of IP packets of unpredictable length, which may be further fragmented/reassembled depending on the capabilities of the equipment through which they pass.
By design, IP packets are /allowed/ to follow a route that is, superficially at least, unpredictable: you can inspect your own router configuration to work out where your "next hop" is going but after that all bets are off until a TCP message is reassembled at its destination.
If any form of load balancing is used between the source and destination, then the precise routing /will/ be unpredictable: a TCP stream is likely to be split over multiple physical connections, and other protocols- UDP, ICMP etc.- might be routed differently.
You can use traceroute to get an idea of what route will be used, but that won't paint a reliable picture of any load balancing etc. In addition, traceroute usually relies on either UDP or ICMP so might follow a very different route from TCP: if it even works at all, since some networks consider that sort of probe to be hostile and block it.
The plethora of "options" applicable to TCP and IP, not to mention non-standard facilities provided by router manufacturers, can often be used to get more detail: unless they're blocked at some point. But the bottom line is that it's not generally possible to say "I've sent a 50Kb TCP message, I want to know exactly how that was split into IP packets and the route each followed".

Most implementations of load balancing choose a path based on a hash of header fields that are stable for a particular connection, unless the paths are extremely identical. They do this because they know that TCP is likely to create more overhead traffic if the packets arrive in a different order than they were sent.
